# Circle with cyclic quadrilateral angles with tangent

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to answer the following questions. As you can see, I have done the first part but cannot make headway with the second part.

PTQ is the tangent to a circle at the point T. The points A and B  on the circumference of the circle are such that TA and TB make acute angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with TP and TQ respectively. If AB meets the diameter through T at N, prove that TN = $\frac{a \sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos(\alpha - \beta)}$, where a is the length of the diameter. 
If the points C and D on the circumference of the circle are such that  TC and TD make acute angles $\gamma$ and $\delta$ with  TP and TQ respectively and CD meets the diameter through T at the same point N, prove that $\tan \alpha\tan\beta = \tan\gamma\tan \delta$

[image]

Comment: Equate the expression for $TN$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with the expression in terms of $\gamma$ and $\delta$. Expand the cosines. Divide-through by something convenient.

Comment: Thanks! That’s it.  I’m trying to vote for you but it says I can’t vote for my own question.

Comment: Well, I only gave a comment, not an answer, so it's not upvotable. :) ... In any case, you should post your completion of the problem as an answer so that we can upvote your success. (You should also accept your answer when possible, so that the system doesn't repost it in the future.)

Comment: OK. Thanks.  I’ll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final working for the problem
 [image]

Comment: Are you reducing something that looks like $p/(q+p)$ to something that looks like $(p/q) + 1$ on each side separately? That would be an incorrect argument (although the result happens to be correct).